# gitlab pages returns 404 with trailing dot in hostname

Tags: dns, gitlab, gitlab-pages

I want to add a CNAME to my DNS to resolve www.spfweb.co.uk to spfweb.gitlab.io

In all good DNS documentation, it seems my www CNAME record should resolve to spfweb.gitlab.io. (i.e. with a trailing dot) [btw, I've not set this up yet...]

However... http://spfweb.gitlab.io/ is good and works, but http://spfweb.gitlab.io./ results in a 404

Would my CNAME record be wrong? (i.e. against good DNS advice, it would not end with a trailing dot to work), or is gitlab not checking hostname correctly? Indeed, if I make it resolve to spfweb.gitlab.io (without trailing dot), it actually resolves to spfweb.gitlab.io.spfweb.co.uk

If you look at other websites - even gitlab.com itself, http://gitlab.com./ works as expected.

So, whichever way one I use, it doesn't work: with trailing dot, gitlab returns 404. Without trailing dot, DNS is resolved incorrectly?!

Comment: Trust the "good DNS documentations" and append a dot.

Comment: @tkaust thanks, that's what I thought. But if I do that gitlab reports 404. I've done some other changes; give DNS about 6 hours to timeout, then resolve www.spfweb.co.uk - and browse to http://www.spfweb.co.uk/ to see what I mean.

Comment: I just tested it locally, gitlab doesn't know about your other domain. I don't know gitlab that good, but you need to configure gitlab so it understands that `www.spfweb.co.uk` and `spfweb.gitlab.io` are the same thing.

Comment: https://about.gitlab.com/2016/04/07/gitlab-pages-setup/#custom-domains Did you add your second domain to your gitlab project?

Comment: @tkausl - ah - I didn't, no.   I've added it now - and BOOM!  Yes, it's working thank you.Interestingly, that link suggests the CNAME record should NOT have a trailing dot!  Thanks

Comment: @tkausl if you want, write an answer and I'll accept it

Comment: @tkausl  just doing a bit of house-keeping on my questions - if you're still interested writing an answer, I'll accept that.